# Question about monit file change alert

Tags: files, filesystem, monitor, monitoring, monit

I am currently using *ossec* to monitor files changes to my server.

I saw that Monit has file changes alarm as well, but I do not know how to configure it. I tried to search but I cannot find sample configuration.

Can you give an example config for monit to monitor if there is a changes to

- */etc*
- */var/www*
- */bin*
- */sbin*

Also is there a way for monit to ignore changes to *.php* and *.js* files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check the checksum of a file (e.g. sshd_config) you could use:

```
 check file sshd_bin with path /usr/sbin/sshd
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin
```

In /etc/monit/templates/rootbin is defined:

```
 if changed checksum      then alert
```

I've not tested it with whole directories but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

use small script running by cron

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -t 20
checkdir="/bin /sbin"
filedb="/var/tmp/permsecdb"
email="test@iamroot.ru"

out=$(
exec 2>&1
umask 266
find $checkdir -type f -printf "%m\t" -exec md5sum {} \; >$filedb.tmp
diff $filedb $filedb.tmp
mv -f $filedb.tmp $filedb
)
if [ "$out" ];then 
 (date; echo; echo "$out") | mail -s "Change permsec `hostname`" $email fi
```

script create md5 base, and compare in next call

author:
https://kmsvsr.ru/2014/04/09/monitoring-izmenenij-fajlov-v-linux/